# Groupby with forward looking rolling maximum

Tags: python, pandas, max, rolling-computation

I have data with date, time, and values and want to calculate a forward looking rolling maximum for each date:

```
Date        Time    Value   Output
01/01/2022  01:00      1.3   1.4
01/01/2022  02:00      1.4   1.2
01/01/2022  03:00      0.9   1.2
01/01/2022  04:00      1.2   NaN
01/02/2022  01:00      5     4
01/02/2022  02:00      4     3 
01/02/2022  03:00      2     3
01/02/2022  04:00      3     NaN
```

I have tried this:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date','Time'], ascending=True)
df['rollingmax'] = df.groupby(['Date'])['Value'].rolling(window=4,min_periods=0).max()
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date','Time'], ascending=False)
```

but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: can you show calculation for each row? how'd you get 1.3 for first row?

Comment: 1.3 is just the value, the 1.4 is the calculation (in the output column)

Comment: the first table and second were not matching, hence the confusion

Comment: first table is probably unnecessary to show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a shifted reverse rolling max:

```
n = 4
df['Output'] = (df[::-1]
 .groupby('Date')['Value']
 .apply(lambda g: g.rolling(n-1, min_periods=1).max().shift())
 )
```

Output:

```
         Date   Time  Value  Output
0  01/01/2022  01:00    1.3     1.4
1  01/01/2022  02:00    1.4     1.2
2  01/01/2022  03:00    0.9     1.2
3  01/01/2022  04:00    1.2     NaN
4  01/02/2022  01:00    5.0     4.0
5  01/02/2022  02:00    4.0     3.0
6  01/02/2022  03:00    2.0     3.0
7  01/02/2022  04:00    3.0     NaN
```

Comment: its a 56m row database, is that going to blow up my computer?

Comment: How many days do you have? This might take some time but should work.

Comment: 5 years * 365 days = 1,825 days

Comment: OK so no so many compared to the total rows. I can't predict but this shouldn't be too be bad (the worst case with `groupby` is to have a lot of small groups). Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: What do I do if "n" changes for each date? Some dates have 4 unique values, some have 5, some 6, etc?

Comment: Then don't use a `rolling.max` but `cummax`: `.apply(lambda g: g.cummax().shift())`

Comment: ok yes works and is surprisingly fast only a few moments for the entire db

Comment: Yes `cummax` is faster than `rolling` ;)